# Capture registry change and re-apply them when needed

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Is there a way to capture a registry change and re-apply it to other PCs?

We have few PCs and we do configure programs like Outlook and other things in a special way to suit our needs, and now it is a painful process to do that for each PC/user.

Is there any way to capture the changes so we can apply them again?

Answer (score 1):

Process Monitor does a good job of capturing registry changes, but it doesn't seem to include any way to save the logged changes as REG files that could be applied again later.  Still, it may be helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

[NirSoft RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) can apparently capture registry changes to a .REG file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out RegSnap
It will take a snapshot before and after a change and show you all the settings that are different. This can also include file changes.  Handy tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into configuring some of these settings by group policy? The [Office Resource Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303401(office.12).aspx) has tools for creating Group Policies which control Office settings. You can read more about it in [KB 924617](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924617). Another possibility would be to customize the installer to set certain settings up. You can read about that in [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179233(office.12).aspx).

> The Office Customization Tool (OCT)
>   helps you configure how Microsoft
>   Office Outlook 2007 is installed on
>   users' computers. This tool enables
>   you to include custom settings and
>   Outlook profile configurations in a
>   Setup customization file that is
>   applied when Office Outlook 2007 is
>   installed from a network installation
>   point.
>
> **Customizing Outlook by using the
>   Office Customization Tool**
>
> You can use the OCT to customize the
>   following aspects of your installation
>   of a network installation point for
>   Office Outlook 2007:
>
> Specify installation states for
>   Outlook features
>
> - Specify Outlook user settings
> - Customize profiles and (optionally)
>     export profile settings to a PRF file
> - Configure Send/Receive settings for
>     Microsoft Exchange accounts
>
> After your initial installation, you
>   also use the OCT to modify and deploy
>   updates to customizations.

Most Microsoft products, and a lot of third party products, can be set up to do administrative or customized installs so that settings are applied ahead of time. The [Internet Explorer Administration Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817415.aspx) can customize all of your IE settings, for example, and while not officially supported, there are ways to [customize a Firefox install](http://nathanhinkle.com/firefox-custom-installation/) as well. Try googling "product name + custom install" or "... + administrative install"

Comment: thanks, what I was looking for is a way to avoide many software kits!
some other programs does not have kits!

Comment: Hm. I see your point there, and would definitely look at process monitor as mentioned in the other post. However, I believe that you will probably find it easier in the long run to use the official methods rather than trying to figure out each reg setting yourself, especially since some settings aren't even stored in the registry.